# how to fix Server Error in '/' Application. error in visual studio mysql c#. below are my code

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# and still learning of it.
i'm setting up a phone book web to store my data to MySql database .There is none error in it ,but it came out with Server Error in '/' Application.

i have try debugging it but it still came out with the same problem

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type '_Default'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
>
> Line 2:
>
> Line 3:
>
> Source File: /default.aspx    Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

below are the code

```
namespace Phonebooks
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234");
    public _Default()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BTN_INSERT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO contacts(name,position,h/pno,company's name,address,post code,state,country,tel,did,fax,email) VALUES('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtposition.Text + "'," + txthpno.Text + "','"+txtcompanyname.Text+"','"+txtadress+"','"+txtpostcode.Text+"','"+txtstate.Text+"','"+txtcountry.Text+"','"+txttel.Text+"','"+txtdirect.Text+"','"+txtfax.Text+"',"+txtemail.Text+")";
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);

        try
        {
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Not Inserted");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        connection.Close();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Post the full error message

Comment: Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

Comment: Post the full error message

Comment: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Comment: Post the full error message. Click on page showing error, Ctrl A, Ctrl C, Edit question, Ctrl V, format as code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use CodeFile at the place of CodeBehind on your aspx page first line

Comment: thanks a lot did solve the problem but it came out with this InitializeComponent(); error

Comment: can you explain what initialize componentis doing there

Comment: You can't access that directly but this might help you https://forums.asp.net/t/1838727.aspx?How+to+get+InitializeComponent+in+web+design+ASP+net

Comment: CodeFile will not solve problem. It basically ships your source code along with aspx file and compiles when requested for that page. This means you wont get a dll when all pages in your application have CodeFile instead of CodeBehind. It is just a workaround for the problem. The real solution is to use fully qualified namespace for the Inherits attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have missed namespace in your page directive.
 Correct your first line in Default.aspx file from

> Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default"

to

> Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Phonebooks._Default"

Comment: thanks a lot  did solve the problem but it came out with this    InitializeComponent(); error